# Parameter estimation using dlmModReg

Tags: dlm

I am trying to use dlmModReg to estimate the regression coefficient lambda (fixed) of the explanatory variable x (27 zeroes followed by one) as applied to the Nile data. My code is this -

```
y <- Nile
x <- cbind(c(rep(0, 27), rep(1, length(y) - 27)))

buildModReg <- function(v) { 
  dV <- exp(v[1]) 
  dW <- c(exp(v[2]), 0) 
  m0 <- v[3:4] 
  dlmModReg(x, dV = dV, dW = dW, m0 = m0)  
}

varGuess <- var(diff(y), na.rm = TRUE) 
mu0Guess <- as.numeric(y[1])
lambdaGuess <- mean(diff(y), na.rm = TRUE)
parm <- c(log(varGuess), log(varGuess/5), mu0Guess, lambdaGuess)  

mle <- dlmMLE(y, parm = parm, build = buildModReg)
if (mle$convergence != 0) stop(mle$message)
model <- buildModReg(mle$par)

filt <- dlmFilter(y, model)
filtered <- filt$m[-1, 1] + x * filt$m[-1, 2]
```

When I run it, the result (W(model)) correctly shows the variance of lambda to be zero. However, the filtered values of lambda (filt$m[-1, 2]) is not constant, but keeps changing from -3 to -244. Any idea why?